# Debugging OOM Exit Code 137 on circleci Linux 4GB RAM instance

Tags: linux, scala, playframework, circleci

We have tests that run on an 8GB RAM instance with no problems but when downgrading to 4GB, the tests abruptly stop and exit with code 137. I ssh'd into the instance and followed the output of `top` but the %MEM used does not go above 5%.

The tests run fine locally using no where near even 1GB RAM as well. Could the number of vCPUs be an issue?
https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#resource_class

```
~$ dmesg | grep -i oom
[97139.572780] node invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x24000c0, order=0, oom_score_adj=0
[97139.572824]  [<ffffffff8118a335>] oom_kill_process+0x205/0x3d0
[97139.572833]  [<ffffffff811f431d>] mem_cgroup_oom_synchronize+0x30d/0x330
[97139.573080] [ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss nr_ptes nr_pmds swapents oom_score_adj name
[107600.844934] postgres invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x24000c0, order=0, oom_score_adj=0
[107600.844978]  [<ffffffff8118a335>] oom_kill_process+0x205/0x3d0
[107600.844984]  [<ffffffff811f431d>] mem_cgroup_oom_synchronize+0x30d/0x330
[107600.845178] [ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss nr_ptes nr_pmds swapents oom_score_adj name
```

Someone on ##linux recommended this command which I'm not sure how to parse.

Otherwise what are the steps one should take to debug this?

If this helps this is a scala play app with these options.

```
  SBT_OPTS: "-Xmx2G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -Xss2M -Duser.timezone=GMT"
  JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx2G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -Xss2M -Duser.timezone=GMT"
```

Comment: "invoked oom-killer" means your processes are being killed because the system is running Out Of Memory. The exit code of 137 (128+9) is because the process receives signal #9 (SIGKILL). Check the max memory usage with `env time yourcommand` (maxresident), and if you still believe there should be plenty of RAM left over, check your overcommit settings.

Comment: How much swap space do you have?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I typed `swapon --all` and `swapon --summary` after ssh'ing into the circleci instance and nothing was outputted.

Comment: @thatotherguy after ssh'ing into the machine i don't see the `env time` command.`~$ env time java env: ‘time’: No such file or directory` What are overcommit setting?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick The swap line in `top` output shows `KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 free,        0 used. 51574592 avail Mem `. P.S. Side note that the tests run without problems on the 8GB RAM circleci instance (but 4GB should have been enough, it's a small application that runs fine on my laptop, limitting it to 4GB RAM)

Comment: OOM killer is dependent on virtual memory (RAM + swap). How much swap does your laptop have?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick That may be the issue. I'm running on a Mac which looks like it dynamically allocates swap memory (?). I followed https://circleci.com/docs/1.0/oom/, sorted `top` using `Shift + M` and  it seems that the java command is going over 2G under `RES` so it may not be following `SBT_OPTS` or `JAVA_OPTS`. I'm currently looking further in that direction. 
Is there an article somewhere detailing OOM being a combination of RAM / Swap? I'd bring it up with CircleCi to see if they can add more swap memory.

Comment: https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand016.html shows the conditions that trigger OOM - it says that the system looks at both RAM and swap.

Comment: The overcommit tuning that @thatotherguy mentioned is documented in https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/overcommit-accounting